# JQuery Flags not working

Tags: jquery

I'm sure it's a simple problem, and has an obvious answer, but the fact of the matter is I can't work it out. Basically, if the div is clicked, and the variable exists, do this, if not, do that. But none of it works.

Ideas?

```
$("#lisea").click(
            var set = false;
            if(set) {
                function() {
                    $("body").animate({
                    opacity: 1
                    }, 500);
                    var set = false;
                }
            }
            if(!set) {
                function() {
                    $("body").animate({
                    opacity: 0.25
                    }, 500);
                    var set = true;
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: set will always be false since you set it false on every click

Comment: Wrap the current content click into a function. Check set variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your code inside a callback function - not just as a parameter. You're also just defining a function in your condition - you need to invoke it.

Anyway I think this is probably what you want:

```
var set = false;
$("#lisea").click(function(){
    $('body').stop().animate({
        opacity: (set) ? 1 : 0.25
    }, 500);
    set = !set;
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/upqTZ/

Comment: or you can just remove the function altogether

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the 'var', it should work. You are declaring many variables in different scopes.
also not sure if 'set' is some keyword.. so better use some other variable name. like 'if_flag_set'

Comment: And yeah.. it should be $("#lisea").click(function(){... plus the very first line set = false will keep setting it to false. just remove that line! (no need to define outside ;) ) if you declare a variable without 'var' it will become global!

Comment: `Set` isn't a reserved word in JavaScript. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. You seem to declaring the same variable again and again.. 
Move your declaration to outside the scope of the click event..

```
var set = false;
$("#lisea").click(
            if(set) {
                function() {
                    $("body").animate({
                    opacity: 1
                    }, 500);
                    set = false;
                }
            }
            if(!set) {
                function() {
                    $("body").animate({
                    opacity: 0.25
                    }, 500);
                    set = true;
                }
            }
        );
```